# How to find the validation list for a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has validation rules, such that the cell displays a drop-down list of valid answers. These answers are held elsewhere in the spreadsheet, but there are a lot of them, the names are complex, and the sheets are often hidden.

I would like to find the place in the spreadsheet where those valid answers are stored.

How can I navigate the Excel VBA objects to find, from the cell, where this list of answers is?

Comment: You can use Go To feature with Special option: Data validation directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ShowValidValues()
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim vValidation As Variant
    Dim vList As Variant
    Set oCell = ActiveCell
    On Error GoTo noval
    vList = oCell.Validation.Formula1
    If Left(vList, 5) = "=list" Then
        vList = Mid(vList, 2, 99)
        Dim oRange As Range
        Set oRange = Range(vList)
        Sheets(oRange.Parent.Name).Visible = True
        Sheets(oRange.Parent.Name).Activate
        oRange.Activate
    End If
noval:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

This will find the list from the current cell, make the sheet visible, switch to it, and activate the cell range.

Answer (score 1):

You use Data > Data Validation from the ribbon to set the validation for a cell via a popup dialog. If you do the same for a cell that already has validation set then the popup shows the validation that was previously set.

If that validation is a list then the source range for the list is shown and clicking on the little spreadsheet icon next to the source range takes you to it.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to do it in code as part of a larger automation.

Comment: That's fair enough. You might want to make it more obvious in your question that you wanted a VBA answer as I had assumed you'd only resorted to VBA because you couldn't find it in the UI. :-)